# One submit button for several textarea fields php/html

Tags: php, html

I am working on this table in which there will be 10 different projects (Jupiter, Uranus, Saturn, etc..) and in each row, there is a comment section for the user to add updates. As shown in the screenshots, each row has its own "add record" button but I want there to be one "submit" button at the bottom of the table to update multiple comment sections. 
Currently, only one textarea can be submitted.
[image]

Here is a snip from the table file:

```
 echo "<h3> Welcome ". $username; 
 echo "<h3> Form Data </h3>";
 echo "<table border='1'>";
 echo "<tr>
 <th>Project</th>
 <th>%Completed</th>
 <th>Comments</th>
 </tr>";
 echo "<tr>
 <td>Jupiter</td>
 <td>78%</td>
 <td>";?> <form action = 'summary.php' method="post">
 <textarea name="text1" rows="2" cols=15></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="value1" value="Add Record"> 
</form>
<?php "</td>
 </tr>";
 echo "<tr>
  <td>Uranus</td>
 <td>69%</td>
 <td>";?> <form action = 'summary.php' method="post">
 <textarea name="text2" rows="2" cols=15></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="value2" value="Add Record"> 
</form> <?php


 echo "</table>";
```

Here is a snip from the summary file:

```
    <?php


$PC1 = $_POST["text1"];
$PC2 = $_POST["text2"];

//Display in table 
echo "Table updated by: " .$_SESSION['appusername'];
 echo "<table border='1'>";
 echo "<tr>
 <th>Project</th>
 <th>%Completed</th>
 <th>Comments</th>
 </tr>";
 echo "<tr>
 <td>Jupiter</td>
 <td>78%</td>
 <td>$PC1</td>
 </tr>";
 echo "<tr>
 <td>Uranus</td>
 <td>69%</td>
 <td>$PC2</td>
 </tr>";

 echo "</table>";



?>
</body>
```

Any advice would be excellent

Comment: What do you mean "only one textarea can be submitted"?

Comment: If you refer to the screenshots, in each comment section of each table, there is an "add record" comment. I need to just have comment boxes in each row but only one "add records" button to submit multiple comments all at once.

Comment: I mean that only one comment can be submitted the way it is now

Comment: Well, you have two forms, seems like you just need one. Put the whole table inside it.

Comment: You have multiple forms.  Just wrap the textareas in one form with one submit button.

Comment: Also, unrelated, but you shouldn't use multiple `echo` statements like that (it's valid, but kinda ugly and hard to maintain). For HTML templating, close the PHP tag with `?>` and append HTML directly, by using `<?= value ?>`  whenever you need it.

Comment: what's with the edit here @AkhtarMunir ? https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21458578  and your comment *"You are using table so you should icons instead of add button, but it's a table so u can't use one button in a table, update ur answer"* - You are attempting to communicate here. I know you can't reply due to your low rep. Please don't do that; you could be flagged for it.

Comment: I know it's really ugly. I plan on cleaning it up after I get the basics down. Thanks so much for your help everyone. That solved my issue!

Comment: From a UI standpoint, just make sure the button is obvious.  I find long forms with buttons out of view, really confusing.  You can have as many Submits as you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```html
<form>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>project 1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input name="projects[1][comment]"></td>
      <td><button name="submit_id" value="1">Comment</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>project 2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input name="projects[2][comment]"></td>
      <td><button name="submit_id" value="2">Comment</button></td>
    </tr>
  <table>
  <button name="submit_id" value="all">Submit all</button>
  
</form>
```

Any submit button inside `<form>` will send whole form to the server, but using `submit_id` value you can make decision which fields you need to process with this request: comment of one particular project, or all comments.

Project 2 button:

[image: Button for project 2]

«Submit all» button:

[image: Submit all button]

Answer (score 0):

Write a javascript code to get all the values from the input. Add a class to the inputs like 'planets' and get them all by the javascript code
    $('.planets')
and then iterate over the planets read the values to an array and send that to server.

```
$(function(){

$('#sender').on("click", function(){

var pl = $(".planets");
var data = [];
pl.each(function(){
    data.push($(this).val());
});

serverData = JSON.stringify(data)

document.writeln(serverData)

});

});
```

pass serverData to server using ajax and do json decode to convert back to array and use it to store wherever you want.